# Spin Glass Hamiltonian

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-spin, hamiltonian, spin-models

Why do Edwards and Anderson use the hamiltonian
$$
H = \sum_{i,j} J_{ij} \mathbf{s}_i \cdot \mathbf{s}_j
$$
to describe the interactions in a spin glass?

Naively I would think that from the interaction energy $U = - \mathbf{m} \cdot \mathbf{B}$ for a dipole $\mathbf{m}$ in a magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$, and the formula
$$
\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}) \propto \frac{3 \mathbf{\hat{r}}(\mathbf{m}\cdot \mathbf{\hat{r}}) - 5 \mathbf{m}}{r^3} 
$$

for the magnetic field generated  at a displacement $\mathbf{r}$ from a dipole, that the Edwards Anderson  hamiltonian amounts to a neglecting of the  $3 \mathbf{\hat{r}}(\mathbf{m}\cdot \mathbf{\hat{r}}$) term.  What is the purpose of this neglect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Not a dipole interaction**
One reason is that actual interactions between spins are not necessarily dipole interactions. E.g., [RKKY interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RKKY_interaction) is often present and significantly stronger than the dipole interactions.

**Model Hamiltonians and critical behavior**
Another reason is that [Anderson-Edwards Hamiltonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_glass#Edwards%E2%80%93Anderson_model), like the other similar  Hamiltonians inspired by the [Ising model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model), aims not at modeling the details of the spin interaction, by the global thermodynamic/critical behavior - notably at capturing different phases of matter (paramagnetic, ferromagnetic, spin glass, etc.) Although originally such model Hamiltonians were suggested ad-hoc, the development of the renormalization group approach has shown that the [critical behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_phenomena) is independent on the particularities of interaction - even more, the system of different physical nature may be in the same criticality class!

Comment: Referring to the RKKY wikipedia article, is the interaction between spins in manganese impurities in copper (i.e. the example suggested by Anderson and Edwards) of the type: "inner d-electron spins interacting through conduction electrons"?